Form Header textbox value changes with record set when scrolling through continuous form? in Access
I'm trying to set up a Continuous form in Access that provides information for an employee task list (i.e. Supervisor name, Employee name, Due date, Status, etc.).
In the form header, the supervisor name is displayed in a text box with tasks listed in the details section. When scrolling through the tasks listed in the details, I'd like the textbox displaying the Supervisor name to change when reaching the employees/tasks for the next supervisor.
(The SQL query pulls in all active tasks, regardless of the listed supervisor, and displays each record as a continuous form in alphabetical order by Supervisor)
SQL Code for query:
SELECT [tblAssociate_1].[FirstName] & ' ' & [tblAssociate_1].[LastName] AS SuperName,
       tblAssignments.CompletedDate, [tblAssociate].[FirstName] & ' ' & [tblAssociate].[LastName] 
       AS EmpName, tblAssignments.AssignmentID, tblAssignments.AssocID, tblAssignments.CreatedDate, 
       tblAssignments.CreatedBy, tblAssignments.Inactive, tblAssignments.InactiveDate,
       tblAssignments.InactiveReasonID, tblAssignments.ExpirationDate, tblAssignments.AssignmentTypeID 

FROM (tblAssignments LEFT JOIN tblAssociate ON tblAssignments.AssocID = tblAssociate.AssocID) 

LEFT JOIN tblAssociate AS tblAssociate_1 ON tblAssignments.SuperID = tblAssociate_1.AssocID 

GROUP BY [tblAssociate_1].[FirstName] & ' ' & [tblAssociate_1].[LastName], tblAssignments.CompletedDate, 
         [tblAssociate].[FirstName] & ' ' & [tblAssociate].[LastName], tblAssignments.AssignmentID, 
         tblAssignments.AssocID, tblAssignments.CreatedDate, tblAssignments.CreatedBy,
         tblAssignments.Inactive, tblAssignments.InactiveDate, tblAssignments.InactiveReasonID, 
         tblAssignments.ExpirationDate, tblAssignments.AssignmentTypeID   
HAVING tblAssignments.Inactive = False AND tblAssignments.ExpirationDate >= Date(); 

Currently, the textbox value will change when clicking on the a record in the details section.

Have you tried requery on the supervisor name text box (something like Me.txtSuperName.Requery) from the form's current event?

@HansUp yes but it still didn't change. I even tried that same scenario on Lost Focus, Mouse Wheel, and Paint. Same results. It won't change unless I physically click on a field.

Clicking in a field selects that record, making it the active or current record.  Are you perhaps scrolling without changing the selected record?

Yes that's correct. What I'm wondering is if there is a way to make that happen? By using a set focus, a view? Or am I looking at making a change to this form

How about after click a field to select a record, you press the down arrow key to make the next record the selected record. Keep doing that until you get to one associated with a different supervisor.  Then does the supervisor name text box get updated correctly?

So that did work, however, for this instance that wouldn't work with 360 records. Using the down arrow cycles through all the controls on that continuous form line. There are 5 controls for each record that provide the task information.

OK.  You can go into the Access options to change key behavior. Or you could use the page down key.  But I don't think that's what you want.  Instead you want to scroll through the records without changing the selected record, yet have the supervisor name textbox updated to match one (which one?) of the visible records.  Unfortunately Access isn't designed to operate that way.

@HansUp Thank you for working through this with me. I'm limited by my company restrictions for platforms and Access wasn't my first choice. I will rethink how I'm pulling records. :)
